# DOS Assembly program reading from pipe

Tags: assembly, dos, io-redirection, dosbox

As a mental exercise I am re-acquainting myself with DOS assembler. I set up DOSBox to write and test programs and noticed that it lacked a "more" command, so I decided to write my own. The general flow is:

1. Read arguments from the command line
2. Open file named on command line (3dh, int 21h)
3. Read file into memory (3fh, int 21h)
4. Close file (3eh, int 21h)
5. Display file 23 lines at a time, pausing for space bar or q
6. Exit

The program works great when run with a filename as an argument. I then wanted to expand it to work from redirected input, so I added a test to see if stdin had any data (function 0bh, int 21h) and, if so, set the file handle to 0 for stdin.

The problem is that, once the data is read into the buffer and the file closed, key presses don't work (still being redirected?) The first 23 lines of the file are displayed along with the "more" prompt, but then it's stuck. What is the proper way to get redirected input and still be able to access the keyboard?

Comment: Perhaps not the solution you're looking for, but how about reading from port `60H` for your prompt to get a scancode (assuming that still works in your scenario)?

Comment: That's a good idea. I'd still like to know, though, if there is a "best practice" for working with redirected stdin.

Answer (score 1):

You may use BIOS interrupt 0x13 to read the keyboard.

Real MS-DOS will call interrupt 0x13 indirectly when reading the keyboard using interrupt 0x21.

I'm not sure if DOSBox supports interrupt 0x13.

Comment: You mean interrupt 16h.  13h is the disk interface...  DOSBox should support it since it would be hard to run any DOS program without BIOS interrupt support.  It's a rare app of any complexity that didn't make at least a few BIOS calls!

Comment: I ended up using BIOS int 16h. It did indeed do the trick. Thank you for reminding me. It's been awhile.